# What is this Stackoverflow.red?

Tags: discussion

What's all about stackoverflow.red? I found it in google search, it contains deadlinks but updated just with same content as stackoverflow.
http://www.stackoverflow.red/
Suspicious or anything else?

- Is it another website of stackoverflow?for some other region or country? (But I have not found it in the drop down of stack exchange websites)
- Or someone copying their content.

Comment: It should be just a clone. The sign-in button doesn't work, the jQuery isn't fetched from the CDN, everything makes this site suspicious.

Comment: Did a [whois check](http://who.is/whois/stackoverflow.red).

Comment: Content copying at its best, real time updation, @Jamie Yea already gone through this.